# Referencing Enterprise Geodatabase feature classes from ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-pro

When using ArcPy with the ArcGIS Desktop (10.4.1) architecture I am able to set a variable to a feature class and make a feature layer from it using the code below:

```
rock_unit_table = "Database Connections\\TEST PROD [personal].sde\\Test.TEST.DETAILED_SURFACE_COMP"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(rock_unit_table, "rockUnit_lyr")
```

but when I try to do something analogous using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro 1.3.1:

```
rock_unit_table = r"Databases\TEST PROD [personal]\Test.TEST.DETAILED_SURFACE_COMP"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(rock_unit_table, "rockUnit_lyr")
```

I get an error (with some anonymizing applied):

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "N:\path\Test.py", line 324,
>   in 
>       arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(rock_unit_table, "rockUnit_lyr")   File "C:\Program
>   Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 5607, in
>   MakeFeatureLayer
>       raise e   File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 5604, in
>   MakeFeatureLayer
>       retval = convertArcObjectToPythonObject(gp.MakeFeatureLayer_management(*gp_fixargs((in_features,
>   out_layer, where_clause, workspace, field_info), True)))   File
>   "C:\Program
>   Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing_base.py", line
>   506, in 
>       return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True)) arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not
>   valid. ERROR 000732: Input Features: Dataset Databases\TEST PROD
>   [personal]\Test.TEST.DETAILED_SURFACE_COMP does not
>   exist or is not supported Failed to execute (MakeFeatureLayer).

In ArcGIS Pro I can see the feature class under Databases in the Project pane so I think it is my syntax in ArcPy that is astray.

Can anybody suggest what may be astray with the syntax that I am trying to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems as you cannot use this shortcut any longer. When the `Database Connections` special folder is dragged into the Python window in ArcMap, you get:

`r'C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.4\ArcCatalog\'`

This is because there is only one `Database Connections` per user, that is it is a universal source of all your enterprise database connections.

However, in ArcGIS Pro,  `Databases` is specific to a project, that is every project will have its own `Databases` shortcut. When you drag the `Databases` into the Python window, you get:

```
"GDB"
```

There is no data path to the actual folder where the .sde files are stored. Thus, you won't be able to supply the Databases shortcut when running your `arcpy` scripts targeting ArcGIS Pro.

Trying to supply:

`r"GDB\db.sde\esrigdb.DBO.DataLines"` or `r"Databases\db.sde\esrigdb.DBO.DataLines"` just won't work.

Since you are always working with a specific ArcGIS Pro project, I'd get its `homeFolder` and then use `os.path.join` to get the database path:

```
proj = mp.ArcGISProject(r"C:\Users\%username%\Documents\ArcGIS\Projects\MyProject\MyProject.aprx")
print(proj.homeFolder)
C:\Users\%username%\Documents\ArcGIS\Projects\MyProject
```

The .sde connection files are stored in the project `homeFolder`.

```
arcpy.Describe(os.path.join(proj.homeFolder,'spatial_db.sde','esrigdb.DBO.DataLines')).shapeType
'Polyline'
```

Comment: In my case the `*.sde` file is not located in the `homeFolder` but your answer enabled me to piece together what I needed to do.  I'll post an answer describing that.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this using the [answer from @AlexTereshenkov](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/236296/115) to arrive at this workflow.

1. In the Project pane of ArcGIS Pro 1.3.1 I right-clicked on the enterprise database connection under Databases to open its Properties
2. I copied its Name e.g. `N:\path\SDEfiles\TEST PROD [personal].sde` (`SDEfiles` is simply a folder that I created to place `*.sde` files into)
3. Ran this test which printed `Polygon` and worked without error:

---

```
import arcpy
rock_unit_table = r"N:\path\SDEfiles\TEST PROD [personal].sde\Test.TEST.DETAILED_SURFACE_COMP"
print(arcpy.Describe(rock_unit_table).shapeType)
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(rock_unit_table, "rockUnit_lyr")
```